# SelectOneMenu's value is always 0 in the backing bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

I have a problem with getting the selected value.

It is always 0.

XHTML file:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="SelectDicimalsInput5" value="#{auction.money}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="1" itemValue="1"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="5" itemValue="5"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="10" itemValue="10"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="100" itemValue="100"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="500" itemValue="500"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="1000" itemValue="1000"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Backing bean :

```
@ManagedBean (name="auction")
@RequestScoped
public class AuctionBean implements Serializable {
    private int money;
    //getters & setters ...
}
```

Comment: `0` is the default value of primitive `int` (`private int money;`). Do you get `0` on post-back? Take a `@ViewScoped` bean (`javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped`) instead.

Comment: still got the same problem.

Comment: Do you have a surrounding `h:form`?

Comment: Try `<p:ajax event="change" />` to submit value on every change event.

Comment: When is it evaluated to `0`? When the form is submitted synchronously or partially through AJAX? It is very unlikely to reproduce the problem with a view scoped managed bean I presume.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your `selectonemenu` selected value is a `String` and your variable in the backed bean is an `int`.

So this selected value can't be converted to `int` and that's why you always get `0` as *the defailt value of the primitive type int* here.

You have to convert this `String` into an `int` to match the variable type, you can use an **[IntegerConverter](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/javax/faces/convert/IntegerConverter.html)**:

```
<f:convertNumber integerOnly="true" />
```

and your code will be:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="SelectDicimalsInput5" value="#{auction.money}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="1" itemValue="1"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="5" itemValue="5"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="10" itemValue="10"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="100" itemValue="100"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="500" itemValue="500"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="1000" itemValue="1000"/>
<f:convertNumber integerOnly="true" /> //This converter should be added
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Also note that there's the `converter="javax.faces.Integer"` attribute that can be used with  `<h:selectOneMenu>` elements but I think it's not supported by primefaces, but may be I am wrong, so you can try :

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="SelectDicimalsInput5" converter="javax.faces.Integer" value="#{auction.money}">
```

Comment: The `javax.faces.Integer` converter is inferred, when a component is bound to a property of type `int` or `Integer`.

Comment: Yes but all that we can deduce here is that value is not taken from the web page, and I think it's a convertion problem.